# is it a good practice to store data in memory in a django application?

Tags: python, django

I am writing a reusable django application for returning json result for jquery ui autocomplete.

Currently i am storing the Class/function for getting the result in a dictionary  with a unique key for each class/function.

When a request comes then I selects the corresponding class/function from the dict and returns the output.

My query is whether is the best practice to do the above or are there some other tricks to obtains the same result.

Sample GIST : https://gist.github.com/ajumell/5483685

Comment: Could you clarify the question with a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very general question. It primary depends on the infrastructure of your code. The way your class and models are defined and the dynamics of the application.

Second, is important to have into account the resources of the server where your application is running. How much memory do you have available, and how much disk space so you can take into account what would be better for the application.

Last but not least, it's important to take into account how much operations does it need to put all these resources in memory. Memory is volatile, so if your application restarts you'll have to instantiate all the classes again and maybe this is to much work.

Resuming, as an optimization is very good choice to keep in memory objects that are queried often (that's what cache is all about) but you have to take into account all of the previous stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more doubt. If the query lookup returns a larger result will it stay in the memory and is there any method the optimise memory usage.

Comment: Indeed, QuerySets in Django are very optimized by a pattern call "Lazy loading" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) With this, you only access an object just when it is required, thus, the memory is not filled with big objects when parts of their fields are not yet required.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to know if there is a manual way to clear memory used by a function.

Comment: Well, the easiest answer that comes to mind is using the `del` python keyword. If you want a more sophisticated mechanism of object disposal we will need to go deep into google ;)

Comment: In this case delete is not possible. I have to return the array from my function. In the application which I am working there will be more than 10k data and will generate very large output. Is there any other method that you know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, manually deleting will involve a `del` somewhere most certainly. If you have to return the big array you may delete it in the method that requested it. You can also encapsulate the array into a class and define a method `dispose` which can `del self` or something like that and return the reference to that class. I think that will be a good subject for other question, comments allow too few characters to give a good answer :(

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be talking about a form of memoization.

This is OK, as long as you don't *rely* on that result being in the dictionary. This is because the memory will be local to each process, and you can't guarantee subsequent requests being handled by the same process. But if you have a fallback where you generate the result, this is a perfectly good optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Storing a series of functions in a dictionary and conditionally selecting one based on the request is a perfectly acceptable way to handle it.

If you would like a more specific answer it would be very helpful to post your actual code.  And secondly, this might be better suited to codereview.stackexchange

Comment: In which file should the dictionary be put according to best practices? Eg., in a new file (if so, is there a convention for naming it?), in views.py, or in models.py?